# Prove by contrapostivie; how do you not a set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

The question is

> Proof by contrapositive: show that (A - B) ∩ (B - A) = ∅.

So the contrapositive is ¬(∅) = ¬((A - B) ∩ (B - A)).

What I've got is, ¬(∅) = (A - B) ∪ (B - A).
If that is correct, then I could prove by using a direct proof to show that the union is not an empty set.

For example, let a, b, c ∈ A and c, d, e ∈ B.
A - B = a, b
B - A = d, e
The union would be a, b, d, e, which is not an empty set.

However, I don't see how using the contrapositive here actually proves the statement, so I believe that I'm doing something wrong here.

I've found this question in *Mathematics: A Discrete Introduction* 2nd ed. by E. Scheinerman. It is question 19.8 and the hint in the back of the book is

> Suppose (A - B) ∩ (B - A) ≠ ∅. This means there is an element *x* in both *A - B* and *B - A*. Argue from here to a contradiction.

Comment: The complement $\bar{A}$ is what you are looking for, along with DeMorgan's Laws.

Comment: Are you sure it's proof by contrapositive and not proof by contradiction?

Comment: @ Mitchell Kaplan I've just quoted it exactly as is.

Comment: @WP0987: contrapositive is usually about an implication. So you can talk about the contrapositive of $A\implies B$. I don't know that you can talk about the contrapositive of an equality. I think you have written the statement wrong. Is there any more context to the problem?

Comment: @Thomas: I've found some more information that will help.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you want to do a proof by **contradiction**, not contrapositive.

Anyway, so you assume that $(A - B) \cap (B - A) \neq \emptyset$. Then there and element $x\in (A - B) \cap (B - A)$. That is
$$
(1)\quad x\in A - B \\
(2)\quad x\in B - A.
$$
Now (1) says that $x\notin B$ and (2) says that $x\in B$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: As I'm searching for information on this, there seems to be slightly different definitions about proof of contrapositive. My book lists proof by contrapositive under proof by contradiction. And the question itself comes from the book. Is this really about using two forms of proof? I need to use proof by contradiction and proof by contrapositive.

Comment: @WP0987: No, this is just a proof by contradiction. I don't understand why you keep insisting on the contrapositive proof. To prove that A imples B the contrapositive is that not B implies not A. But your problem is not of the form: prove that if A then B.

Comment: The reason why I'm insisting on a contrapositive proof is that a contrapositive proof is what my professor has required for me to give in order to solve the problem. If I don't follow directions, then I won't receive credit regardless of the rightness of the proof. Maybe the reason why I'm having so much trouble is because the publisher made a mistake in creating this problem and it shouldn't be about using contrapositive. Is there anyway to convert the problem into an A then B so not B then not A kind of problem?